# setAttribute to checkbox with servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, checkbox

here is what I have:

JSP:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="no_del_file" <% 
if ("True".equals(request.getParameter("no_del_file"))) {
    out.print("checked=\"checked\"");

} %>/>

<%String test = request.getParameter("no_del_file"); %>


 <p><%=test%></p>
```

Java:

```
 boolean cbState = request.getParameter( "no_del_file" ) != null;
            System.out.println("cbstate: "+cbState);
            if (cbState == true) {
                request.setAttribute("no_del_file", "checked");
                String checker=(String) request.getAttribute("no_del_file");
                System.out.println(checker);
            }

 RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/runButtonCommand.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

The problem is that the output is:

```
 cbstate: true
 checked
```

The test gives "on" as print after submitting the form

but the checkbox is not checked itself after the servlet returns the responds. The tick is removed for some reason.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<% if(request.getParameter( "no_del_file" )=="checked"){%>
<input type="checkbox" id="no_del_file" name="no_del_file" value="no_del_file" checked>
<%}%>
```

Comment: doesn't work. It still is unchecked after submitting the form

Comment: Dont use `==` to compare equality between two strings, use `.equals` instead. For that matter don't use plain java code in a code snippet in jsp.

Comment: after changing it to "checked".equals(requst......) it still doesn't work

Comment: It says "on" after reloading

Comment: Try with request.getAttribute().It may works hopefully

Comment: It says on after reloading

Comment: Try with request.getAttribute().It may works hopefully

Comment: getAttribute or getParameter deliver the same result.. it says on in the <p> block after submitting and the tick is removed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171700/discussion-between-viking-and-shamsher-khan).

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it figured out... If someone is interested here it is

```
 <%String test = (String)request.getParameter("no_del_file"); %>
<%String checked = "";%>

<% 
if ("on".equals(test)) {
    checked="checked=\"on\"";

} %>
<input type="checkbox" name="no_del_file" <%=checked%>>
```

It returned on when checked